# Windows10にVisual Studio Build Tools 2019をインストールできない

Tags: windows, visual-studio

Windows10 HomeにVisual Studio Build Tools 2019のインストールを試みていますが、
存在しないディスク領域に対する容量不足の警告により、インストールできない状況です。
なお管理者権限で実行しています。

ダウンロードは [Visual Studio for Windows および Mac のダウンロード](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ja/downloads/) から行いました。

#### 問題

画像の通り、Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 存在しないディスクドライブ (`G:`) の領域不足を指摘し、インストールが終了してしまいます。

[image]

[image]

[image]

なお、C:\ドライブには200GB以上空き領域があり、その状況で空き領域不足と指摘されるのは理解が及びません。
その他にもD:\を指定すると「パスが適切ではない」とのエラー表示が出てしまい、先に進めない状況です。
[image]

#### 試した・判明した事柄

- 仮想マシン上に構築したWindows10にはインストールできました。
- [同様のエラー](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/packageidmicrosoftvisualstudiobrandingenterprisepa-6/784899) に遭遇している報告をUS版コミュニティフォーラムで発見したものの、投稿者の情報不足により進展はなし。

#### 個人的な考察

仮想マシン上のWindows10にはBitLockerが走っていないが、問題が起きているSurface 7 ProではBitlockerが適用されている為、Bitlocker特有の領域保護は障壁になっているのではないかと推測しています。

#### エラーログ

```
インストールに問題が発生しました。

次の手順に従って、パッケージ エラーのトラブルシューティングを行うことができます。

    1. 個々のパッケージ エラーに対して、以下の検索 URL を使ってソリューションを検索する
    2. 影響を受けるワークロードまたはコンポーネントの選択内容を変更してから、インストールをやり直す
    3. マシンから製品を削除してから、もう一度インストールする

この問題が既に Developer Community に報告されている場合は、そこからソリューションまたは回避策を見つ
けることができます。問題が報告されていない場合は、他の開発者がソリューションまたは回避策を見つけることができるように新しい問題を作成することをお勧めします。Visual Studio インストーラーでは、右上隅の [フィードバックの提供] ボタンを使って新しい問題を作成できます。

================================================================================

パッケージ 'Microsoft.Build.UnGAC,version=16.10.2.2130804,chip=neutral,language=neutral' のインスト
ールに失敗しました。
    検索 URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.Build.UnGAC;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=10069
    詳細
        リターン コード: 10069
        リターン コードの詳細: "Microsoft.Build.UnGAC" をインストールするための十分な領域がありませ
ん。ドライブ G:\ には 20000000 が必要ですが、0 しかありません。
    影響を受けたワークロード
        C++ によるデスクトップ開発 (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools,version=16.10.31205.180)
        MSBuild Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools,version=16.0.28516.191)
    影響を受けたコンポーネント
        C++ コア デスクトップ機能 (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Core,version=16.2.29012.281)
        C++ コア機能 (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreIde,version=16.10.31205.252)
        MSBuild (Microsoft.Component.MSBuild,version=16.5.29515.121)
        テキスト テンプレート変換 (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating,version=16.0.28625.61)
```

#### 補足

空き領域を写した画像を貼り忘れていました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

G:\という把握していない領域について。正直当方も把握しておりません。いつ頃から存在したのかも不明です。またディスクの一覧は次の通りです。

[image]

Comment: 共有コンポーネントの欄や各エラーメッセージにちらほらみかける`G:`ドライブが気になりますが、これは以前存在したが現在存在しないストレージ領域か何かですか？

Comment: はっきり申し上げると私にもわかりません。いつ頃から存在したのか？それともSurfaceの仕様でこうなっているのかも不明な状態です。念のためディスクの管理コンソールから取得したディスク一覧を上げておきます。

Comment: 最初のスクリーショットの情報からすると、この記事の内容が関連してそうです。[Visual Studioの共有コンポーネントのディレクトリを変更する](https://kmmr.jp/post-125/)

Comment: ありがとうごさいます。上記の方法で解決しました。お力添えに感謝します。